# Environment Texture does not illuminate the landscape in Cycles

Tags: texturing, lighting

my environment texture doesn't illuminate the landscape in Cycles, it's just all black, but the texture can be seen. Scene World and Scene Lightning are activated. Do you have to activate anything else? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm sorry but I am unfortunately not allowed to pass on the blend file. With over 1GB it is also quite large because there are a lot of objects. Strangely, in the Evee Render, the objects are brightened by the background texture. Just not in Cycles.

Comment: In the Properties panel > World > Ray Visibility, check if the Diffuse option is enabled. Also you could share your file without all the objects of your scene, just pack the image

Comment: just "simplify" your scene to just your problem - so delete all objects except default cube - thats enough but with environment texture.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. I'll upload it in a moment!

Comment: I would like to ask downvoter to provide a reason in comment, so Tim knows what to make better. Thank you ... @Tim to share file use https://blend-exchange.com and copy paste given code into your Q via Edit.

Comment: Sorry that I’m only getting in touch now, but something else came up with me. When I deleted the objects, the problem became clear to me. It was a sphere over the whole landscape that blocked the light and was invisible. The settings have already been correct, I just have to delete the sphere. But thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

It was a sphere over the whole landscape that blocked the light and was invisible. The settings have already been correct, I just have to delete the sphere :)